# Assistance Finishing Modulo Proof

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation

For this problem we have that $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime and $ab$ mod $n$ = $ac$ mod $n$. We need to show that this proves that $b$ mod $n$ = $c$ mod $n$.

So far I have: 
Let $a$ and $n$ be relatively prime and $ab$ mod $n$ = $ac$ mod $n$. Since $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, by the Theorem GCD as a Linear Combination, we have that there exists $s,t\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $1=as+nt$. Since $ab$ mod $n$ = $ac$ mod $n$, this implies that $n|(ab-ac)$. We need to show $b$ mod $n$ = $c$ mod $n$ or $n|(b-c)$. Notice,

$$ab-ac=a(b-c)$$

I am having trouble finishing the proof from here. I know somewhere we are going to have to use the fact that $1=as+nt$ but I am unsure how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know Euclid's Lemma, which states that: For integers $x,y,z$, if $x\mid yz$ and $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, then $x\mid z$?

If you have this result available, then since $n\mid ab-ac=a(b-c)$ and $n$ and $a$ are relatively prime, you can conclude that $n\mid b-c$.

Comment: oh wow! I must have skipped over that theorem in my notes when i was looking through to find helpful theorems. thank you !